# Grouping multiple values to a single date in pandas/numpy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set consisting of Date, Latitude, Longitude. On some days there are multiple Lat/Lon values on the same day. I'm looking for a way (either numpy or pandas or xarray) to change the structure so I have the Dates as an index and when I choose a single date I get a list of the Lat/Lon values from that Date. The idea is to be asle to neatly plot location by day.

I appreciatwe any ideas you might have.
The df currently looks like this:

```
       Date        Lat        Lon
```

623  01/04/2023  32.889517  34.724117
624  01/04/2023  32.889550  34.724133
625  01/04/2023  32.889617  34.724183
626  01/04/2023  32.889700  34.724200
627  01/04/2023  32.890033  34.724250
..          ...        ...        ...
618  31/03/2023  32.856350  34.710267
619  31/03/2023  32.856700  34.710283
620  31/03/2023  32.856700  34.710300
621  31/03/2023  32.856700  34.710300
622  31/03/2023  32.857017  34.710350

I tried using pandas series:

Date=pd.Series(Times)
Lat=pd.Series(lat,index=Date)

I tried with pd.sort_values(['Date', 'Lat'], inplace=True)

In both instance I got multiple entries of dates with the corresponding Lat/Lon values.
I'm looking for perhaps Dates as columns with Lat and Lon as rows.

Thanks